# How to data fetch only one column using the other column

Tags: java, android-studio

Logically wrong.. im new on Android java database.. theres no error but i think you guys get my point.

```
getSearch = searchbar.getText() .toString();
searchquery = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE tagalog LIKE '%"+ getSearch +"%';";
sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(searchquery,null);
Cursor c = wordsDBHelper.getdata(sqLiteDatabase);
searchRes.setText( c.getString(2).toString());
```

any suggestion is accepted. After pressing this button where this code located at, the Button direct to the mainActivity.

```
heres the logcat
    01-26 13:28:49.285 32177-32177/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-26 13:28:49.305 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
01-26 13:28:49.305 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
01-26 13:28:49.305 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17980: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
01-26 13:28:49.305 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-26 13:28:49.305 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
01-26 13:28:49.305 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17984: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
01-26 13:28:49.305 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-26 13:28:49.315 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 125K, 27% free 2723K/3728K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-26 13:28:49.315 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 7.125MB for 4651212-byte allocation
01-26 13:28:49.325 32177-32183/com.example.leoandroid.translate D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 7265K/8272K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-26 13:28:49.355 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-26 13:28:49.355 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 433: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-26 13:28:49.355 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-26 13:28:49.355 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-26 13:28:49.355 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 455: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-26 13:28:49.355 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-26 13:28:49.435 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate I/PGA: Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 32177, tid = 32177
01-26 13:28:49.445 32177-32177/com.example.leoandroid.translate I/PGA: New SOCKET connection: com.example.leoandroid.translate (pid 32177, tid 32177)
```

Kindly help. i tried to analyze it and i analyzed Attempting to create new socket connection... which redirect it to the Mainactivity? im confused.

Comment: if you need just one column, you can change your SQL query like `SELECT <required_column_name> FROM words ...`

Comment: ill add one more column so ill leave it like that. im just having the force stop on this code of the button

Comment: im asking if my cursor is right.. is that right? im highly suspicious on my cursor syntax.. get me in touch thanks

Answer (score 2):

Better to do with function. Create function in your DbHelper class like

```
     public DataProvider getInformations()
         { 
                  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                  Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select "+your column+" from "+TABLE_NAME, null );
                    res.moveToFirst();
                    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();
                    while(res.isAfterLast() == false)
                    {
                        dataProvider.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Columnname)));
                        res.moveToNext();
                    }
                db.close();
                return dataProvider;
         }
```

Then your Main activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    userDbHelper =new UserDbHelper(this);
    DataProvider dataProvider=userDbHelper.getInformations();
    text = dataProvider.getText();

    }
```

Comment: Pash can i add you on any social community? like facebook. i have to ask questions about this. For example on your given code how did you .getText() .toString(); the end user output..

Comment: Here is my button code Pash.. `btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               /*Pash is this where i Put the MainActivity Code you say? kindly help tnx*/

            }
        });`

Comment: not yet man. i got a class named DataProvider.. can we go on private message?

Comment: set following lines in your onCreate                                                    userDbHelper =new UserDbHelper(this);
    DataProvider dataProvider=userDbHelper.getInformations();         and this line --> getSearch = dataProvider.getText(); in btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: onCreate of DataProvider class? or on MainActivity button.

Comment: yes please. heres my DataProvider class `public class DataProvider {
    private  String bsya;
    private String tglog;




    public String getBsya() {
        return bsya;
    }

    public void setBsya(String bsya) {
        this.bsya = bsya;
    }

    public String getTglog() {
        return tglog;
    }

    public void setTglog(String tglog) {
        this.tglog = tglog;
    }

    public DataProvider(String bsya,String tglog){
        this.bsya= bsya;
        this.tglog= tglog;


    }



}`